# Java: How to run consecutive async calls in order with Vertx?

Tags: java, loops, asynchronous, vert.x

lets say we have following situation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    String alphabet = "AB";
    String[] splittedAlphabet = alphabet.split("");

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(splittedAlphabet);
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    final int number = i;

    //async call
    vertx.setPeriodic(1000, id -> {
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next() + " i: " + number);
        } else {
            vertx.cancelTimer(id);
        }
    });

}
}
```

We have an outer `for`-Loop and an inner `vertx.setPeriodic{}`-Loop which prints asynchronously the index number `i` . The outer `for`-loop fires for each index  number five asynchronous calls of the inner `Vertx`-Loop. This inner Loop is iterating through every character (in our case 'A' and 'B'). That means every  indexnumber is combined with every character, which are asynchronously called. Thats why there is no guarantee for order in the output. 
Thats what I got:

```
A i: 1
A i: 2
A i: 5
A i: 4
A i: 3
B i: 4
B i: 5
B i: 1
B i: 3
B i: 2
```

But what I want to  get is (and keep the inner loop asynchronous):

```
A i: 1
A i: 2
A i: 3
A i: 4
A i: 5
B i: 1
B i: 2
B i: 3
B i: 4
B i: 5
```

Is that possible?

Comment: 'Consecutive async' is a contradiction in terms, and so is 'async in order'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution by myself:

```
private static Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String alphabet = "AB";
        String[] splittedAlphabet = alphabet.split("");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(splittedAlphabet);
        iterate(list.iterator());
    }

    public static void iterate(Iterator<String> characters) {
        if (characters.hasNext()) {
            asyncCall(characters);
        } else {
            vertx.close();
        }
    }

    private static void asyncCall(Iterator<String> characters) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(1);
        numbers.add(2);
        numbers.add(3);
        numbers.add(4);
        numbers.add(5);

        Iterator<Integer> numberIterator = numbers.iterator();
        final String character = characters.next();

        vertx.setPeriodic(1000, id -> {
            if (numberIterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(character + " i: " + numberIterator.next());
            } else {
                vertx.cancelTimer(id);
                iterate(characters);
            }
        });

    }
```